# Jquery JSTree Check duplicate nodes

Tags: jquery, jstree

[image: Example Tree]

I want to be able to select all the nodes that are Child node 3 (they all have an id of cn3) Currently when I do the following

```
$("#ks_sectors").jstree("check_node", $("#cn3"));
```

It only selects the first Child node 3 as shown above. How do I select all?

Comment: `cn3` duplicate ID .. is your problem.. make it `class`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. I do want the duplicate ids. That's how the structure of the XML is. Are you saying its not possible with IDs and I should just give each duplicate element a class with the same name? Would other JSTree functions still work then?

Comment: The id selector is used to specify a style for a single, unique element. The class selector is used to specify a style for a group of elements. Unlike the id selector, the class selector is most often used on several elements. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Comment: Quick question. Since applying class works in the example above, What's the quickest way to apply a class with the same name as the id to all the nodes in jquery tree?